# Receiving multiple files using Http Endpoint in Mule

Tags: html, mule

I have the following html, which uploads multiple files to the URL `http://localhost:5000/intake`:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:5000/intake" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple   />
  <input type="submit" value="Send now" >
</form>
```

But in Mule, I always receive only one file.

This is my mule config:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="5000" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>

<flow name="simpletestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/intake" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="POST"  responseStreamingMode="NEVER"/>
    <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="For Each">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:/Users/U595036/AnypointStudio/Production/upload/src/main/wsdl" outputPattern="#[key]" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

The `#[message.inboundAttachments]` always has only one file in it, even if the browser sends many.

Comment: You should run your POST message through a TCP monitor and have a look at the raw message, to see if there are multiple parts. This will help you determine where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Mule can handle only one file at a time(A thread per record),In your case you can upload your files to a folder and through ftp you can process the flow.